# how to impliment antnet in adhoc network using ns2

Tags: shell

Can anyone tell me how to impliment antnet in ns2? i  am getting this type of error in  antnet routing algorithm  using NS2. Is it possible to implement?
Please help me out.How to solve this type of problem ?

```
admin123@admin123-virtual-machine:~$ cd /home/admin123/Desktop/NS/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/tcl/ex
admin123@admin123-virtual-machine:~/Desktop/NS/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/tcl/ex$ ns antnet.tcl
num_nodes is set 12

    (_o3 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o3 cmd node-config-adhocRouting AODV -llType LL -macType Mac/802_11 -ifqType Queue/DropTail/PriQueue -ifqLen 1000 -antType Antenna/OmniAntenna -propT..."
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o3" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$ns node-config-adhocRouting AODV\
                        -llType $val(ll) \
                        -macType $val(mac) \
                        -if..."
    (file "antnet.tcl" line 33)
admin123@admin123-virtual-machine:~/Desktop/NS/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/tcl/ex$
```

Comment: [tag:tcl] != [tag:shell] but apart from that I really don't know what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an executable 'ns' with no AntNet.

HOWTO antnet, ns-2.35 :

tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

cd ns-allinone-2.35/

patch -p0 < antnet_ns235.patch

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNY29xLTUwd213ZUE/view?usp=sharing

./install

cd ns-2.35/ && sudo make install

cp ns ns-antnet && sudo cp ns-antnet /usr/local/bin/

Simulation : ns-antnet antnet.tcl

→ **Note** : "AntNet" is not working very well. The suggestion is to use "**anthocnet**"

→ See  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5345798#post5345798

-

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)